# Can I set a 'nuke' password for an encrypted secondary drive?

Tags: 14.04, encryption

I have an encrypted 2TB HDD, and I would like to be able to enter a password at the decrypt step of mounting it, that will render the drive un-decryptable. I have seen a few article online about this but I don't know how to go about doing this. I am hoping someone else on here has already done this sort of thing.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, and I can wipe the drive if I have to, as it isn't holding anything important right now.

Comment: Assuming your passphrase is strong enough, what is the difference, to you, between wiping the drive and not giving anyone the passphrase?  Either way the drive's contents are as good as random data.

Comment: Well, I would like to be able to make the data inaccessible by anyone if I have too. If I don't have a nuke password, then there is a chance I will be coerced into providing my decryption password.

Comment: If you are afraid about strong decryption tools like soldering iron I-will-not-say-where, you'd better think about mechanical ways to destroy data ;)